# Is there a way I can use a Galaxy Note on Virgin Mobile?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note, mobile-network

I want to know if it is possible to use a Samsung Galaxy Note on Virgin Mobile's network.  If so how would I go about setting it up?  Virgin doesn't currently offer the Note, so I can't just buy it from them.  So would buying an unlocked version and calling Virgin's customer service to activate the phone on their network work?

Comment: What are you asking for? Can you re-edit your question to make it clearer :)

Comment: @t0mm13b Are the edits clearer?

Comment: Makes more sense :) Just realized by looking at Chahk's answer below, is your Galaxy Note CDMA radio based? I would have thought there'd be a CDMA based version of the Note? :o

Comment: @t0mm13b I don't have a Galaxy Note.  I was just thinking about getting one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in the USA. Virgin Mobile USA's network is CDMA, while the Galaxy Note is a GSM phone.

Virgin Mobile UK is a GSM network, so Galaxy Note will work on it.  Although depending on whether the phone and the carrier use the same frequencies for 3G, you may only get 2G speeds.

Comment: Well that sucks.  The Galaxy Note looks awesome.

Comment: Rumors are that because original GNote sold so well, Samsung is readying a Galaxy Note 2 for this fall.  Hopefully they will release it on more carriers this time around.

Comment: Yes, I saw the tweet about the Gnote2 coming out later on this autumn... http://www.gsmarena.com/exclusive_galaxy_note_2_to_have_55_screen_remains_narrower_than_original_note-news-4455.php

Comment: Yeah, I heard about it as well.  Hopefully they make a CDMA version.